# angular 5 get code from google oauth2 returned url

Tags: angular, angular5

this is drajngo rest and angular 5 project.
im trying to add google social auth to my project at this moment google respond `code` that we should sent it to backend api..

how can i get code from url when we redirct again to home page? i tried like this but `no value found` block will run

this is redirected url from goole that contain a code:

http://localhost:4200/?code=4%2FAAAhk4vGOH4MAdsPJdmf_2zMtEK_odMwTdaQiOQAnUZTaCpIbDQ7aB66h99DEvFVkdW7Q7ojtXkrzsJVdzeGbCY

this is my routes config for home page:

```
this is my appRoutes = [
  {path: '', component: ProductComponent},
  {path: ':code', component: ProductComponent},
]
```

component:

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }


  private param1;
  ngOnInit() {

          this.route.params.subscribe((param: Params) => {
      this.param1 = param['code']
      if (this.param1) {
        console.log(param['code'])
      } else {
        console.log("no value found")
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your redirect URL in google to something like this:

http://localhost:4200/product

2. Change your app routes like this:

> ```
>  appRoutes = [
>       {path: '', component: ProductComponent},
>       {path: 'product', component: ProductComponent},
>     ]
> ```

Read query params like this:

```
this.sub = this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
        this.code= +params['code']||0; 
    });
```

Comment: although i added`product/:code` to router.ts    i get error 

`
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'product'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'product'
`
after redirect

Comment: Updated the answer, please try now.